# Error when passing varaibles into Firebase Flutter Query Where clause

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So i am trying to perform a query using the where clause. However, there is an error when i am trying to write my code like this.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Announcement_Detail extends StatefulWidget {

  final String docID;
  Announcement_Detail(this.docID);

  @override
  State<Announcement_Detail> createState() => _Announcement_DetailState(docID);
}

class _Announcement_DetailState extends State<Announcement_Detail> {

  final String docID;
  _Announcement_DetailState(this.docID);

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getAnnouncementDetail = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('announcementlist').where('id', isEqualTo: '${docID}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(docID),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code below is where i pass in my variable to the announcement detail class

```
onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Announcement_Detail(announcementlist.id),
                ),
              );
            },
```

The error says the instance member 'docID' cant be accessed in an initializer.

Is there anyway i can pass my variable with data into this query other than need to hard code the data inside the variable ?

Comment: add the full code of this class

Comment: Please check sir @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that you are accessing the `docsID` before even initializing the object. Therefore just move that specific code to the `initState`:

```dart
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> addAnnouncement = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('announcementlist').where('id', isEqualTo: "${docID}");
  }
```

If you want to use `addAnnouncement` in another method, then you have to make it an instance variable:

```dart
final Query<Map<String, dynamic>>? addAnnouncement
```

Comment: Ive updated my code Sir, but how can i use the getAnnouncementDetail ?

Comment: Im trying to user the getAnnouncementDetail to get the data from the collectionGroup from Firebase, can u show me how to get it and display

Comment: If you want to use getAnnouncementDetail in another method, then you have to make it an instance variable:

`final Query<Map<String, dynamic>>? getAnnouncementDetail `

Comment: at which part of the code sir. When i add in the instance variable , the Announcement_Detail(this.docID) has error

Comment: Can u show me ur way how you would do it Sir?